# Open a specific view controller in the storyboard when notification is tapped in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that needs to open a specific view controller when notification is tapped. Here's what I have tried:

In this case, if i use this my app crashes when I tap the notification.

```
if([[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]objectForKey:@"alert"] isEqualToString:@"You've got mail!"])
{
    MTNotificationViewController *profile = [[MTNotificationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MTNotificationViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController: profile animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

If I use this the app doesn't redirect to the view controller that I want it to load. I also tried putting my code in an if statement to check if the app is **UIApplicationStateInactive** and **UIApplicationStateBackground** but I still get the same result.

```
if([[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]objectForKey:@"alert"] isEqualToString:@"You've got mail!"])
{
    MTNotificationViewController *profile = [[MTNotificationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MTNotificationViewController" bundle:nil];
    [navigation.visibleViewController.navigationController pushViewController:profile animated:YES];
}
```

Can somebody please help me.
Thanks!

Comment: What's the error message, it seems you don't init the view controller from nib correctly.

Comment: @Wingzero im not getting any error message. It's just that my app doesn't open the specific view controller..

Comment: you said ` if i use this my app crashes when I tap the notification.` that's what I am asking for trace. you need to give some error message or crash log

Comment: ahh, i cant test notification in debug mode. I can only test it with ad hoc build. For some reason I cant receive notification when im on development.